# return DTEdit table?

Tags: shiny, dt

I am using DTEdit to allow users to edit a datatable in my Shiny app. It works well and displays the user's updates/inserts in the UI. However, I want to be able to perform functions on the updated table. Is there a way to return the updated table to the server side as well as the UI side?

Comment: Hi, it will be much easier to help you if you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dtedit`'s main method to handle user editing of data is by using and defining *callbacks*.

However, `dtedit` does return a `reactiveValues`. Server-side, changes in 'reactiveValues' can be detected in an `observeEvent`.

I have examples of using both the return list of `reactiveValues` and use of callbacks in a [vignette](https://rpubs.com/DavidFong/DTedit), based on [my modified version of DTedit](https://github.com/jbryer/DTedit/pull/5). Previously my version of `DTedit` returns a list of 'reactives', rather than a 'reactiveValues', but now returns `reactiveValues`, just like  [`jryer/DTedit`](https://github.com/jbryer/DTedit/).

Using [`jbryer/DTedit`](https://github.com/jbryer/DTedit/) :

```
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    Grocery_List_Results <- dtedit(
        input, output,
        name = 'Grocery_List',
        thedata = data.frame(
            Buy = c('Tea', 'Biscuits', 'Apples'),
            Quantity = c(7, 2, 5),
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE
        )
    )
    
    observeEvent(Grocery_List_Results$thedata, {
        message(Grocery_List_Results$thedata)
    })
    
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    h3('Grocery List'),
    uiOutput('Grocery_List')
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```